# getting output from excl used to run a shell script

Tags: c, linux, shell, execl

Hi i would like to get suggestions as to getting output from a script which i am supposed to execute from an excl call:

```
void getCurrentFSLSMode(char* const in_fsls_directory, enum Mode* out_mode) {
  int link[2];
  pid_t pid;

  char buffer[MAX_PATH_STR_LENGTH];
  char command_buffer[MAX_COMMAND_STR_LENGTH];
  char script_name[] = "/scpt.sh\0";

  if (pipe(link)==-1)
    printf("pipe");

  if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    printf("fork");


  if(pid == 0) {

    dup2 (link[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(link[0]);
    close(link[1]);
    command_buffer[0] = '\0';
    strcat(command_buffer, in_fsls_directory);
    strcat(command_buffer, script_name);
    printf("%s\n", command_buffer);
    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", command_buffer, (char *)0);

  } else {

    close(link[1]);
    int nbytes = read(link[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    buffer[nbytes - 1] = '\0';

    // LAZY COMPARISON
    // not algorithm name, it's just what im doing.
    // 
    printf("DBG :  %s %d\n", buffer, nbytes);
    if (buffer[0] == 'G') {
      *out_mode = K;
    } else if (buffer[0] == 'K') {
      *out_mode = G;
    } else {
      *out_mode = CLEARED;
    }

    wait(NULL);
  }
}
```

if i use the same code on running a binary, i am able to read out its output,
however, when i try to execute a script such as the one above,  i am only able to read the command issued.

example:

```
excl("binary command to run");
read(output)
output == "correct output"
```

but if

```
excl("shell script to run");
read(output)
output == "shell script to run"
```

why is this?

Comment: You *have* checked that the `read` call succeeds? That the `fork` call succeeds? That the `execl` call succeeds?

Comment: Consider, also, that your script is using STDERR rather than STDOUT

Comment: Oh by the way, what if the script or command result in *more* output than `MAX_PATH_STR_LENGTH` characters?

Comment: The call succeeded, I saw it when I piped my applications output. The script I called simply executed a binary application.

Comment: I checked your code but still can't get what you want to do . can you show your full code of successful binary running version that can execute, and full code of error running version for scripts code? and betrer also paste your scripts